# Concatenate TraversableOnce objects in Scala?

Tags: scala, iterator, concatenation

I want to concatenate a traversable once to a traversable once without resolving either.
This is the solution I have come up with as an implicit, but I don't know if I am missing a native solution...

```
object ImplicitTraversableOnce {
  implicit def extendTraversableOnce[T](t : TraversableOnce[T]) = new TraversableOnceExtension(t)
}

class TraversableOnceExtension[T <: Any](t : TraversableOnce[T]) {

  def ++ (t2:TraversableOnce[T]):TraversableOnce[T] = new concat(t.toIterator, t2.toIterator)

  private class concat(i1:Iterator[T], i2:Iterator[T]) extends Iterator[T] {
    private var isOnSecond = false

    def hasNext:Boolean =
      if (isOnSecond) i2.hasNext
      else if (!i1.hasNext) {
        isOnSecond = true
        hasNext
      }
    else true

    def next():T = if (isOnSecond) i2.next() else i1.next()
  }
}
```

Comment: Maaaybe you'll find it useful: Guava has a set of `concat()` methods in `Iterators` and [`Iterables`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html). I know it's Java, but as a last resort you can convert Scala -> Java -> Scala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can join iterators with ++.  So if you're going to use iterators anyway, just

```
def ++(t2: TraversableOnce[T]): TraversableOnce[T] = t.toIterator ++ t2.toIterator
```

The reason to not do this is to supply an efficient `foreach` for `Traversable`s that are not `Iterable`/`Iterator`, but then you need to fill in all the `TraversableOnce` abstract methods.

Comment: You're right, I don't know how I missed this one, the scala implementation is almost the same as well

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
  def ++(t2: TraversableOnce[T]) = new Traversable[T] {
    def foreach[U](f: (T) => U) {
      t.foreach(f)
      t2.foreach(f)
    }
  }
```